# How to perform an assignment inside a lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, variable-assignment

Python 2.7.1

I would like to understand why I can't do the following which seems like a sensible thing to do

```
def do_stuff():
    # return a function which takes a map as an argument and puts a key in there
    f = lambda map: map['x'] = 'y' #compilation error
    return f 

x = do_stuff()
map = {}
x(map)
print map['x']
```

I can have that lambda function to be somethign simpler something like `f = lambda map: os.path.exists` however I cannot get it to change the map. Can someone tell me how I can achieve this? If this is not possible at all why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use assignment in an expression, it is a statement. A `lambda` can only contain *one* expression, and statements are not included.

You *can* assign to the map though, by using the [`operator.setitem()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.setitem) instead:

```
import operator

lambda map: operator.setitem(map, 'x', 'y')
```

Comment: Actually it is cool !!

Comment: or `map.__setitem__('x', 'y')`

Comment: @newacct: Yup, but that uses the special hook method directly; better to use an API method. :-)